# Special Integral Proof

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, improper-integrals, gamma-function, alternative-proof

How to prove
 $$\int_0^\infty x^{2n-1} \exp(-a^{x^3})\, dx = \frac{\Gamma(n)}{2a^n} ,\quad n> 0 ,\quad  a>0. $$

Comment: The result seems (on the first sight) to be quite untrivial. Where does this come from? Did you try to solve it yourself?

Comment: From Special Functions , I have tried a lot

Comment: For $a=1$ the integrand is $x^{2n-1}\exp(-1)$, and this doesn't give a convergent integral over $[0,\infty).$ Did you mean $\exp(-ax^3)$?

Comment: no i mean $\exp (-a^{x^{3}} )$

Comment: To further develop the comment of @semiclassical: if $a<1$, then the integral diverges.

Comment: suppose that a> 1 , How can i do ?

Comment: I am afraid that what you wrote is simply wrong.

Comment: why ? can you tell me the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you meant is $$\int^{\infty}_{0}x^{2n-1}e^{-ax^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{0}y^{n-1}e^{-ay}\,dy=\frac{1}{2a^n}\int^{\infty}_{0}z^{n-1}e^{-z}\,dz=\frac{\Gamma(n)}{2a^n}$$
where we have used $x^2=y$ and $ay=z$. Otherewise the question does not make sense because for $a=1$ the your integral would diverge while the right side is a finite value.